# Tool for downloading an entire site (recursive and Flash links processing)

Tags: website, download

We need to replicate a working Flash site. The problem is that we don´t have access to the source code (the site is mainly a full Flash site).

What is a tool to recursively download the site? The tool should process [SWF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWF) files
to extract the links in it.
I´ve once used [Teleport](http://www.tenmax.com/teleport/home.htm), but as far as I´m concerned it cannot process SWF.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general way that a program can extract the links from a .swf file. A swf file can contain applets, and these applets can require any resource they feel like.

The best way to do it is probably to use something like wireshark, and see what requests the flashsite is actually doing.